# Process calculation of SAPID on basis of bill start date and bill ENd date in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure where the same `SAP_ID` is inserted thrice. But their `BILL_START_DATE` and `BILL_END_DATE` is different for all the sap id.

Below is the updated information

[image: IMG]

So I want to calculate for each sap id with respect to different start and end date. So is there any way on how to make it differentiate for calculation purpose.

Below is table details

```html
Table: IPFEE_MST_INSRT_BIL

Name                          Null? Type           
----------------------------- ----- -------------- 
SAP_ID                              NVARCHAR2(100) 
R4GSTATE                            VARCHAR2(100) 
BILL_START_DATE                     DATE           
BILL_END_DATE                       DATE           
UPLOADED_MONTH                      VARCHAR2(9)    
UPLOADED_YEAR                       VARCHAR2(9)
```

Also where I want to calculate is the procedure link below

[Procedure link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=023a32efa1b8ff6518abca6680de772c)

**Update**

For ex: If I want to calculate one given rate whose formula is below.

`V_STANDRD_AMT := V_APP_MSA_RATE / r.noofdays;`

Then what i did is.

```
for r in (
  select sap_id, (CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(bill_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') as date)- CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(bill_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') as date)) as noofdays  
   from IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_BIL
 )
loop
```

So from above cursor, I want to calculate `standard amount`.

whose formula is

`STANDRD_AMT := 5000 / no of days`

How it can be achieved ?

Comment: Sorry, but - what are we supposed to do with 1000 lines of code (you posted on db<>fiddle)? Can't you simplify it? What does table (you posted here) have to do with that code? There are 3 references to it - one is DELETE from that table, another is commented (so is irrelevant) and the third is INSERT INTO the table. Which one of these represents "I want to calculate for each sap id with respect to different start and end date. So is there any way on how to make it differentiate for calculation purpose"?

Comment: @Littlefoot: I can explain you: for ex, I want to calcualte for 1st sapid whose date start and end is 1may and 6may respectively. So i want to take the date for that sap id and assign it for calculation. how can I achieve it ?

Comment: Which calculation? Maybe you'd want to select BILL_START_DATE and BILL_END_DATE into local variables and use them elsewhere? Or do it in a loop (as you have 3 rows for the same SAP_ID)?

Comment: yes, I want to use in my SP. for each row there is different start date and end date. so for ex: if one row start date is 1 may and end date is 6 may. so calcualtion I have to make is for 6 days. like that I want to make for all the  multiple sap ids

Comment: @Littlefoot: any update, pls suggest

Comment: @Littlefoot : any help, can we discuss more on this so that you can help

Comment: You said: "for ex: if one row start date is 1 may and end date is 6 may. so calcualtion I have to make is for 6 days" - looks like you want to **subtract** those values, i.e. `end_date - start_date + 1` and then do something with that value.

Comment: @Littlefoot: yes, I need to do the calculation like that. but there are multiple rows. So how will I handle it ?

Comment: You do not provide enough information and your goal/calculation(?) is not clear. On the picture there are 3 start and 3 end dates for a SAPID. Yet, on the example you only calculate one of them. Did you choose that on purpose? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to GROUPY BY the SAP_ID and get a SUM of the date differences. Something like

```
for cur_r in (
    SELECT SAP_ID,
        SUM(BILL_END_DATE - BILL_START_DATE) as SUM_OF_DAYS
    FROM IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_BIL
    WHERE VENDOR_NAME= 'BIL' and SAP_ID in ('I-HR-KKOD-ENB-H002')
    GROUP BY SAP_ID
    ) loop

    V_STANDRD_AMT := V_APP_MSA_RATE / cur_r.SUM_OF_DAYS;

end loop;
```