# Not able to assign values of select to variables in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have defined to `nvachar` variables and I am assigning like below

```
select sap_id, (CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(bill_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') as date)- CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(bill_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') as date)) as noofdays  
into V_SAPID_NOOFDAYS, V_NOOFDAYS 
from IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_BIL;
```

But it's giving me error as

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

how to assign it and use it?

Comment: You haven't said what the error is, you've just repeated your code as a quote. There isn't an `nvarchar` data type; but as you didn't give an [mcre] it's unclear if that's a typo when posting and you actually used `nvarchar2` (or `varchar`), and either way whether you gave it a size. But why would you use a string value - never mind in the national character set - to hold a numeric result? And if your table has more than one row then you'll get a too-many-rows error - you can't put the values for multiple IDs into single scalar variables. It's unclear what you are actually doing though.

Comment: @AlexPoole: updated the question with proper error, please suggest what to do in this case

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the data, and how many rows you expect - as you're including the ID in the result, and don't have a `where` clause, presumably you expect more than one. So you probably want to make that a cursor query and loop over the results; or have a record type and collection type and bulk-collect into that. But which approach to take depends on what you need to do with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning multiple rows, and as you are including the ID in the results and aren't filtering (via a `where` clause) that seems to be what you expect and want.

You could loop over the results, which doesn't need any PL/SQL variables to be defined as the cursor does that internally:

```
for r in (
  select sap_id, (CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(bill_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') as date)- CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(bill_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') as date)) as noofdays  
  from IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_BIL
)
loop
  -- do something with each pair of values
  dbms_output.put_line(r.sap_id || ': ' || r.noofdays);
end loop;
```

Or you could define a record type and collection type, have a collection variable, and bulk collect into the collection. (Or separate collections for the two values, but then you have to keep track of them separately).

It depends what you need to do with the data once you've queried it.

As an aside, your calculation will give you fractions of days, so you might want to trunc or floor it to get an integer, again depending on what you are doing. It also ignores the time zones of the original strings - you are converting the strings to timestamps with time zones, but when you cast to date you're losing that. It's possible that could affect the result even if both times are in the same region, of they cross a DST boundary. But perhaps they're all UTC, so it wouldn't matter anyway. Still, you can subtract the timestamps to get an interval, and then extract the days from that.

Comment: So if I want to check and compare with calculation, so I need use inside end loop our outside.. ?

Comment: Compare what with what? If you want to compare each row with something then do that inside the loop. You can apply a calculation to an individual value inside the loop, or update some running total say, and then check it outside. (Though if that's all you're doing using `sum()` and getting one result back would probably make more sense.)

Comment: actually I want to calculate for same ID's for different dates, that is why i cannot get unique or single value

Comment: ok, can u also help on this.. it's almost the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73152528/process-calculation-of-sapid-on-basis-of-bill-start-date-and-bill-end-date-in-or